# Integration Service drops entires on joining an table

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

i have a special problem with SQL Integarion service 2005 (SSIS). During a stored procedure i fill a table with data. Afterwards i join this table over a varchar column with SSIS and another table, but i miss some of the entries. If i do the same using only SQL server (no SSIS) i get all entires. I know already SSIS has a different mechanism for comparing (on byte level) but i can find, why this entries are missing.

I already compared the length of the text of the entries,checked it by hand, tried differend collation.

Has anyone a idea, how i identify this entires (which missing on SSIS)?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is case-sensitive, so if you are joining on string columns, you may not get some matches.  Given that you've checked for length and collation already, it sounds like this may be the issue.  If this is the problem, you can make the columns Uppercase in the Data Flow to perform the join operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Merge Join component to do the join in SSIS, make sure your source queries are ordering the results by the column you're using to join.

It's a common mistake to set the IsSorted value to True on the source without actually ordering the results in the query with an ORDER BY clause.